# Fit height of div to a floating div?

Tags: css, html, width

Alright this never works when I need to setup two divs (one floating and fixed width) and another div with margin to the size of floating div width.

[image]

I tried clear: both, and some other work arounds. Nothing being successful. Is there an overall better way to do this?

HTML:

```
                        <div class="usercpwrap">
                        <ul class="usercptabs">
                            <li>Account</li>
                            <li>Friends</li>
                            <li>Messaging</li>
                            <li>Reputation</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="usercpcont">
                            Ajax load page content from: /usercp/{page}.php
                            goes here.
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.usercptabs{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 225px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    clear: both;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
}

.usercptabs li{
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

.usercptabs li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}

.usercpcont{
    margin-left: 225px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
.usercpwrap{overflow:hidden;}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Sjen/)

OR:

Clear float.

```
<div class="usercpwrap">
    <ul class="usercptabs">
        <li>Account</li>
        <li>Friends</li>
        <li>Messaging</li>
        <li>Reputation</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="usercpcont">Ajax load page content from: /usercp/{page}.php goes here.</div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clr{clear:both;}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Sjen/1/)

Comment: Thanks, will the floating element adjust to the height of the other div as well?

Comment: If usercpcont has more height than the usercptabs, I want the usercptabs to adjust it's height to the height of usercpcont.

Comment: Try `.usercpcont,.usercptabs{display:table-cell}.usercpwrap{display:table}` in that case.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: @JulianSchmuckli Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

only to double the margin because it overrides the exact length of that floating div

```
.usercpcont{
    margin-left: 550px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give clear:both; after usercpcont DIV

```
<div class="usercpwrap">
  <ul class="usercptabs">
    <li>Account</li>
    <li>Friends</li>
    <li>Messaging</li>
    <li>Reputation</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="usercpcont"> Ajax load page content from: /usercp/{page}.php
    goes here. </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

working fine.